# window.location.hash returns undefined, script will not display correct pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this script to alter my page

```
(function (w, d) {
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var allIds = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var el = allElements[i];
        if (el.id) {
            allIds.push(el.id);
        }
    }

    oldHash = window.location.hash;

    window.onhashchange = function () {
        if (oldHash === window.location.hash)
            return;

        allIds.forEach(function (id) {
            id = "#" + id;
            if (id === window.location.hash) {
                $(".content div:not(.hidden)").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $(".content div:not(.hidden)").addClass("hidden");
                    $(id).fadeIn(400, function () {
                        $(id).removeClass("hidden");
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        oldHash = window.location.hash;
    };
}(this, this.document));
```

It is supposed to alter my page so that when I click links in the navbar this script is called and alters the page to display whatever is under the navbar button's ID. When I click on the "home" button of my navbar my page is supposed to change to www.foo.com/#home .

In practice, the page wont even alter it's hash to www.foo.com/#home. No matter which buttons I click the page will stay as www.foo.com. I am mirroring the site from a github.io address.

```
    <nav id="navbar" class="fixedElement navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <div  class="cats nav collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul id="navbar-ul" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#home" id="home-nav"  >home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" id="about-nav"  >about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#speakers" id="speakers-nav"  >speakers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team" id="team-nav"  >team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tickets" id="tickets-nav"  >tickets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sponsors" id="sponsors-nav" >sponsors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" id="contact-nav"  >contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id='home'  class="hidden" >
    </div>
```

If I open Dev Tools in Chrome and type "console.log(window.location.hash)"  into the console the console returns undefined. Which means that the hash is not altered at all.

1. Why is this? Is there some inherent problem with mirrored webpages that will not allow them to alter their hash?
2. How can I modify this to make my page link to the proper targets?

If I displayed anything incorrectly please let me know so I may make adjustments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be,

Replaced, `window` with `w` and `document` with `d`

```
(function (w, d) {
    var allElements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var allIds = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var el = allElements[i];
        if (el.id) {
            allIds.push(el.id);
        }
    }

    oldHash = w.location.hash;

    w.onhashchange = function () {
        if (oldHash === w.location.hash)
            return;

        allIds.forEach(function (id) {
            id = "#" + id;
            if (id === w.location.hash) {
                $(".content div:not(.hidden)").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $(".content div:not(.hidden)").addClass("hidden");
                    $(id).fadeIn(400, function () {
                        $(id).removeClass("hidden");
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        oldHash = w.location.hash;
    };
}(this, this.document));
```

Comment: Thanks for that! This changes the scope of the variables from global to local, I think. But since the referenced w and d are referring to window and document (which are already global) this shouldn't change anything.